# Sort by predecessor with limited recursion depths

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I have a linked list  like this

```
 LineID      PredecessorLineID SuccessorLineID 
 ----------- ----------------- --------------- 
 3           NULL              2               
 2           3                 815             
 815         2                 1               
 1           815               195             
 195         1                 52
```

I need to sort in a way that the line with no Predecessor comes first then the line that has the first line as predecessor and so on

I can sort it with this query

```
 WITH    q ([LineID], PredecessorLineID,  SuccessorLineID, init, lvl) AS
                        (
                            SELECT  [LineID], [PredecessorLineID],  [SuccessorLineID], [LineID], 1
                            FROM    Lines
                            WHERE   [PredecessorLineID] is null 

                            UNION ALL

                            SELECT   mt.[LineID], mt.[PredecessorLineID],  mt.[SuccessorLineID], q.init, q.lvl + 1
                            FROM    q
                            JOIN    Lines mt
                            ON      mt.[LineID] = q.SuccessorLineID                                 

                            )

    select  * from  q Option ( maxrecursion 4  )
```

This gives the correct result but the problem is the recursion depth. It realy is n - 1. I have a couple of thousand lines and would need to set maxrecursion  to a very high value.

This query needs to be in a view thats why I cant even set maxrecursion and would need to set it as the default for the server.

Is there a way to do that with less recursion?

Comment: The default of 100 isn't sufficient?  For most hierarchies that is sufficient.  The alternative is a table-valued function.

Comment: The recursion depth  for this query is realy the number of lines minus 1 and I have more than 101 lines

Comment: I tried a table valued function but also there its not possible to set the maxrecursion

Comment: I would probably suggest that you assign a line number when you ingest data.  Storing a linked list using a hierarchy is awkward in SQL and potentially prone to problems (cycles) and complex queries.

Comment: I can actually set maxrecursion when I use a  multi-statement UDF. Can you write your first comment as an answer? I still hope someone comes up with a query that doesnt have this deep recursion but using a function is still a good  option to have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't recommend storing linked lists in this fashion in SQL databases.  They are rather cumbersome to deal with.  I mean, hierarchies are fine but they usually do not exceed a depth of 100.  And "one-off" recursive CTEs are fine with unlimited recursion.

That said, you may have a use-case where this is valid.  You can create a UDF and set the recursion:

```
create function udf_get_hierarchy ()
returns @q as table (
    . . .  -- column definitions go here
)
BEGIN
    WITH q ([LineID], PredecessorLineID,  SuccessorLineID, init, lvl) AS (
          SELECT  [LineID], [PredecessorLineID],  [SuccessorLineID], [LineID], 1
          FROM Lines
          WHERE [PredecessorLineID] is null 
          UNION ALL
          SELECT mt.[LineID], mt.[PredecessorLineID],  mt.[SuccessorLineID], q.init, q.lvl + 1
          FROM q JOIN
               Lines mt
               ON mt.[LineID] = q.SuccessorLineID                                 
        )
    SELECT * 
    INTO @q
    FROM q
    OPTION ( MAXRECURSION 0 );
END;
```

If you are creating a function, you might want to pass an argument into it, to just get the hierarchy for a specific id.